# Fix terminal shell to defaults

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, zsh

I don't know much about shells, i just now i use some functions in terminal (like xattr, and npm and so...).

Recently i tried to do something and i don't remember what i did exactly but now for some reason i get this command not found error for every command i try.

And it has this "zsh: " at the begging of the error. i get i somehow changed the shell type but i don't now how to get it back to the default.

I tried:

Enter: exec bash. but i get zsh: command not found: bash.

Go to Terminal > Preferences > General and set "Default login shell". Doesn't work.

Go to Terminal > Preferences > General and set "Command (complete path) and set it to: "usr/bin" (i see that there is a folder there with all the functions). Doesn't work.

Any ideas?

I use macOS bigSur (m1)

Comment: You have edited your zsh startup files https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Intro/intro_3.html probably ~/.zshrc ~/.zshenv or ~/.zprofile So you need to restore from backup or edit them to be correct. Secondly why try to run bash from zsh - what are you really trying to do

Comment: Thanks @mmmmmm isn't bash the original default shell? how do i restore them? i don't have any backup but it should be some default structure of files isn't that?

Comment: No ash isn't the original default shell. The default depends on what the first version of osx you installed voriginally tcsh, from 10.3 or 4 bash from 1.15 zsh

Comment: Creating a new user creates no shell startup files

Comment: What is the output of `echo $PATH`? Also you can change your shell back to bash by typing `chsh -s /bin/bash`, though sticking with zsh would probably be better since it is mostly bash compatible and newer.